# Powershell - Getting an item in an array, and all items after that match

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have a bunch of files, some ending with .a and some with .b. I have already created an array with all these elements, and when I echo them out I get:

```
  1.a
  111.b
  112.b
  113.b
  114.b
  2.a
  111.b
  112.b
  3.a
  111.b
  112.b
  113.b
```

etc.

These will always be sorted in the correct order, with the oldest entries appearing at the start of the array, and the newest at the bottom.

How could I get the latest '.a' file, and all '.b' files since then?

In the above case, I need to return

```
3.a
111.b
112.b
113.b
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `process {}` block, keep an array of entries ending with ".b", added to every time one shows up; empty it whenever a ".a" entry comes along, and dump the last ".a" entry seen, along with the entire available ".b" array, in the `end {}` block.

Basically a fairly standard accumulate-and-release pattern.